# $ g\in C^{2}(\Omega)$ are dense in $f\in C(\partial\Omega)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $\Omega$ a compact set in the complex plane.
How I can show that the space of $ g\in C^{2}(\Omega)$ with a compact support are dense in $f\in C(\partial\Omega)$?

Comment: The only thing that seems puzzling to me is in which sense this denseness should be understood. Usually, $A \subset B$ is dense in $B$ if its closure is equal to $B$. But in your case, functions defined on $\Omega$ are not at all a subset of functions defined on $\partial \Omega$. Of course, they can be restricted somehow, but then teh statement looks more or less trivial to me.

Comment: So you mean dense in some "trace sense" (see Sobolev's spaces)?